# Horizontal Bar across menu on all pages using css

Tags: html, css

I need to design layout as show in image below.

Basic Page layout will have a top banner section as show in black color which will show up if banner is their otherwise hide.

Next I need to fill the page background with gray color and content area should be white.

I need to run a horizontal banner across Navigation/ Menus as show in example below.

I tried  but the horizontal bar which is in green color on fiddle is not showing up aligned to Menu. If I add `margin-top:40px` it create a space of between header and banner section. I tried using `z-index` that didn't work either.

I would appreciate help in this regard based on pure CSS & div containers.
[image]

### DEMO

```css
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0
}
#contentWrapper {
    width: 500px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background: #ccc;
    height: 300px;
    z-index:100;
    position:relative;
}
#BannerBar {
    height: 40px;
    background: blue;
}
#navBar {
    height: 20px;
    background: green;
    margin-top:30px;
}
#logowrapper
{
    height:40px;
    width:100%;padding:10px;
}
#NavigationWrapper
{
    width:100%;
    height:20px;
    background-color:green;
    text-align:center;
}
#footerBar {
    height: 40px;
    background: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="BannerBar"></div>
<div id="navBar"></div>

<div id="contentWrapper">
    <div id="logowrapper">LOGO</div>
    <div id="NavigationWrapper">
        Home | About Us | News | Something
    </div>
</div>

<div id="footerBar"></div>
```

Link to [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/GDDA5/999/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean like this? I added `position:absolute;`, the `width:100%;` and changed the `margin-top` to `60px`. check the DEMO

```
#navBar {
    height: 20px;
    background: green;
    margin-top:60px;
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/GDDA5/1000/)** 
And to get the right backgrounds, add background to the body in grey and change the background from `#contentWrapper`

```
html, body {
    ...
    background: #ccc;
}
#contentWrapper {
    ...
    background: #ffffff;
}
```

**[DEMO(2)](http://jsfiddle.net/GDDA5/1003/)**

Comment: yes, this is what i wanted...sometime brains dont work towards end of days.. I tried position also...anyways thanks..

Comment: No problem, in the DEMO(2) you have the changed background as you wanted.

Comment: I noticed that, This is what my design is more or like http://jsfiddle.net/GDDA5/1006/

Comment: This will get you in to trouble if you add more lines to the logo wrapper, see demo: http://jsfiddle.net/6gDE5/1/
I have posted an alternative solution that will help with this. (UPDATED: with correct link)

Answer (score 1):

You can also do it like this, separated the containers for easier handling:

```
<div id="BannerBar"></div>

<div id="logoWrapper">
    <div id="logowrapper">LOGO</div>
</div>
<div id="NavigationWrapper">
    Home | About Us | News | Something
</div>
<div id="contentWrapper">

</div>
<div id="footerBar"></div><div id="BannerBar"></div>
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/6gDE5/1/)

Depending on how you want to handle the menu, should it get sticky to the top of the screen when scrolling you can do that with javascript.

Answer (score 0):

When you add the same width and margin as in `contentWrapper`, it is properly aligned

```
#navBar {
    width: 500px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

See modified [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GDDA5/1001/)

Answer (score 0):

see this link http://jsfiddle.net/bipin_kumar/GDDA5/1004/

```
#navBar {
    height: 20px;
    background: green;
    margin-top:60px;
    width:100%;
    position:absolute;
}
```